# Convert unsigned char into an integer using PHP

Tags: php, char, type-conversion

I unpack from a binary string into an array:

```
protected function unpack($packet)
{
    return unpack('C*', $packet);
}
```

after that, I get the following array:

```
102 163 29 1
```

The above four char represent an integer. How can I combine them together to represent an integer? For example:

```
$number = some_method([102, 163, 29, 1]);
echo $number; // will show 100
```

Comment: use intval() function

Comment: You can use intval() function for every single element or if you want to convert whole array values to integer then you can use array_map ('intval', $integers);

Comment: @JayGosai Thank you for your help, but array_map will return an array, but I need to combine them into an integer

Comment: @diavolic Thank you for your help. If I put char array into intval(), I always get return 1. intval([108, 163, 29, 1])

Comment: @Thomas.Yu Combine means do you want sum of array values?

Answer (score 0):

```
function some_method ($numbers)
{
  foreach ($numbers as $key => $num)
    $number[$key] = intval ($num);
  return $numbers;
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely not what was asked

Answer (score 0):

For your unsigned byte array that your got from string

```
$b = unpack($packet); // your function result
```

you can get 32-bit Integer in next ways

```
$value =  $b[0] + 256*$b[1] + 256*2*$b[2] + 256*3*$b[3]; // LITTLE_ENDIAN;
```

or

```
$value =  256*3*$b[0] + 256*2*$b[1] + 256*$b[2] + $b[3]; // big endian;
```